# iOS - update multiple CoreData entities & contexts

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am using CoreData in my app and I have two main entities, let's say Cats and Dogs.
I have this method that I use to initialise my context:

```
     - (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
 {
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
 id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
 context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
 }
 return context;
 }
```

It refers to this method in my App Delegate:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
```

Now, at some point, I have to update some data in my Cats entity.

```
           NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Cats"];
            NSMutableArray *catsArrayData = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    NSManagedObject *aCat = [catsArrayData objectAtIndex:i];
    NSMutableArray *catsArray = [aCat valueForKey:@"cat"];
   [catsArray addObject:responseData];
    [aCat setValue:catsArray forKey:@"cat"];
                    NSError *error = nil;
[context save:&error];
```

Then, I want to do the same for my Dogs entity. So I use the same code, but for the dogs entity. It's in another part of my code, so I have to redefine:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
```

But the problem is that even though I save this second context, it is actually not saved. The data isn't there. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It's difficult to identify from the code you've provided, but I doubt you have to redefine the `NSManagedObjectContext`. I'd suggest your problem is related instead to the structure of your code.

Comment: @andrewbuilder Yeah I imagine it is difficult with this code but I wanted to avoid putting the whooole page. But basically both entities are called literally exactly in the same way, just the entity name that changes. But in the second one they are not saved... How could I provide you with more info?

Comment: Some users upload their project or the relevant classes to GitHub. More the point you can remove references to MOC and replace with the code that includes your save method. Above all else I'd recommend you learn about view controller polymorphism, hierarchy and inheritance. The Stanford University lectures by Paul Hegarty on iTunes U are great.

Answer (score 2):

You need implement your own change notification mechanism, This is good source to learn it.  [Multi-Context CoreData](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/).